# Can't filter or retrieve by custom attribute in LDAP using ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add a custom attribute (called rank) to the `inetOrgPerson` person objectclass. Even though it appears that the attribute is getting added successfully, I can't filter by it or retrieve it using `ldapsearch` though I *do* see the attribute with `slapcat`.

I'm using this [osixia/openldap:1.5.0](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) and mounting my ldif with the following run command

```
docker run \
        --env LDAP_DOMAIN="example.com" \
        -p 389:389 -p 636:636 \
        --volume ldif:/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom \
        --name my-openldap-container   osixia/openldap:1.5.0 --copy-service --loglevel debug
```

My ldif:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributetypes
olcAttributetypes: ( 1.1.3.5.1
   NAME 'rank'
   DESC 'The rank of the user'
   EQUALITY integerMatch
   SINGLE-VALUE
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 )
-
add: olcObjectclasses
olcObjectclasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.5.2.16
   NAME 'rankedUser'
   DESC 'User with rank'
   SUP inetOrgPerson
   STRUCTURAL
   MUST ( rank ) )

dn: cn=developer,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: rankedUser
cn: developer
givenname: developer
sn: Developer
displayname: Developer User
mail: developer@gmail.com
userpassword: developer_pass
rank: 3
```

I confirmed that leaving `rank` out of the user definition throws an error so it appears that the attribute is getting added.

**However**, `ldapsearch` can't find it with a filter:

```
docker exec my-openldap-container ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w admin "(rank=3)"
```

returns

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (rank=3)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

Using `(rank=*)` returns similar.

And I don't see `rank` in the response when I get all the objects on the server

```
docker exec my-openldap-container ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w admin "(rank=3)"
```

returns

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (rank=3)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

But I **do** see `rank` when I use `slapcat`

```
docker exec my-openldap-container slapcat
```

```
61e08e36 UNKNOWN attributeDescription "RANK" inserted.
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example
structuralObjectClass: organization
entryUUID: 44ed7b62-08fb-103c-9cac-c5862f1bdce7
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
createTimestamp: 20220113202936Z
entryCSN: 20220113202936.386692Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20220113202936Z

dn: cn=developer,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: rankedUser
cn: developer
givenName: developer
sn: Developer
displayName: Developer User
mail: developer@gmail.com
userPassword:: ZGV2ZWxvcGVyX3Bhc3M=
RANK: 3
structuralObjectClass: rankedUser
entryUUID: 4552226a-08fb-103c-8116-518769f951e0
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20220113202937Z
entryCSN: 20220113202937.046343Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20220113202937Z
```

But for some reason `RANK` is in all caps

Also something that might be related is that I see this in the logs on startup

```
61e08bb1 @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.57+dfsg-1~bpo10+1 (Jan 30 2021 06:59:51) $
    Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
61e08bb1 UNKNOWN attributeDescription "RANK" inserted.
61e08bb1 slapd starting
```

Would appreciate any help on why I can't query on or see `rank`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to mount a schema file to `/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/schema/custom` with the custom attributes. I made a file `schema/custom.schema` with the following contents:

```
attributetype ( 2.25.1 NAME 'rank' DESC 'User Rank' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 ) 
objectclass ( 2.25 NAME 'rankPerson' DESC 'A user with a rank' SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL MUST ( rank ) )
```

And then I mounted it into my docker container

```
docker run \
        --env LDAP_DOMAIN="example.com" \
        -p 389:389 -p 636:636 \
        --volume ldif:/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom \
        --volume schema:/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/schema/custom \
        --name my-openldap-container   osixia/openldap:1.5.0 --copy-service --loglevel debug
```

And now I can filter by rank

```
~/% docker exec my-openldap-container ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w admin "(rank=3)"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (rank=3)
# requesting: ALL
#

# developer, example.com
dn: cn=developer,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: rankPerson
cn: developer
givenName: developer
sn: Developer
displayName: Developer User
mail: developer@gmail.com
userPassword:: ZGV2ZWxvcGVyX3Bhc3M=
rank: 3

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it will definititely help others in that kind of situation. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: it doesn't let me do it for a few days unfortunately. But I will when I can.